# Loan Interest Calculator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, calculator

I have created a simple calculator for loan interest. However it does not calculate the compound interest correctly.

For example, if I add the loan repayment of 1500000 with 2.5% interest over a 30 year period, it should display the Monthly Repayments as 5926.81, however in my code it displays as 7291.67.

What change do I need to make so it calculates the compound interest correctly?

```js
const simpleInterest = document.querySelector('.simple-interest');
const button = document.querySelector('.button');
//const loading = document.querySelector('.loader');
const results = document.querySelector('.results');

function calculateResults(e) {
    // ui elements
    const principal = document.querySelector('#principal');
    const rate = document.querySelector('#rate');
    const time = document.querySelector('#time');
    const monthlyPayment = document.querySelector('#payment');
    const totalInterest = document.querySelector('#interest');
    const totalAmount = document.querySelector('#total');
    // formula variables
    const p = parseFloat(principal.value);
    const r = parseFloat(rate.value);
    const t = parseFloat(time.value);
    
    // calculate total interest
    const interest = (p*t*r/100);
    // calculate monthly payment
    const payment = ((interest + p) / (t * 12)).toFixed(2);
    // calculate total amount paid
    const total = (interest + p).toFixed(2);
    
    if (isFinite(payment)) {
        totalInterest.innerHTML = (interest).toFixed(2) + 'บาท';
        monthlyPayment.innerHTML = payment + 'บาท';
        totalAmount.innerHTML = total+ 'บาท';
        // hide loader
        button.classList.remove('loading');
        // show results
        results.classList.remove('hide');
    } else {
        // show error
        showError('Please check your numbers and try again.');
        // hide loader
        button.classList.remove('loading');
    }
}

function showError(error) {
    // create error
    const errorMessage = document.createElement('div');
    const calculate = document.querySelector('#calculate');

    errorMessage.className = 'error';
    errorMessage.appendChild(document.createTextNode(error));
    simpleInterest.insertBefore(errorMessage, calculate);
    // clear error
    setTimeout(clearError, 3000);
}

function clearError() {
    // remove error
    document.querySelector('.error').remove();
}

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log('Calculating...');
    // show loader
    button.classList.add('loading');
    
    // set timeout
    setTimeout(calculateResults, 2000);
    
    // prevent page from reloading on submit
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<div class="simple-interest">
    <!-- <h2>Simple Interest Calculator</h2> -->
    <form id="calculate">
        <label for="principal" class="principal">
            <!-- <p class="brz-css-bedky">
                <strong class="brz-cp-color2">Loan Amount   <i class="fa fa-usd" aria-hidden="true"></i></strong>
            </p> -->
            <div class="brz-forms2__item brz-css-xpkoa brz-css-jglan brz-css-proqr brz" style="padding: 0px 7.5px 15px 7.5px;">
            <input id="principal" type="text" placeholder="Loan Amount " class="investment-class-form" />
        </div>
        </label>

        <label for="time">
            <!-- <p class="brz-css-bedky">
                <strong class="brz-cp-color2">Loan Term (years) <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></strong>
            </p> -->
            <div class="brz-forms2__item brz-css-xpkoa brz-css-jglan brz-css-proqr brz" style="padding: 0px 7.5px 15px 7.5px;">
                <input id="time" type="number" placeholder="Loan Term (years)" class="investment-class-form"/>
            </div>
            
        </label>

        <label for="rate" class="rate">
            <!-- <p class="percent brz-css-bedky">
                <strong class="brz-cp-color2">Interest(%)</strong>
            </p> -->
            <div class="brz-forms2__item brz-css-xpkoa brz-css-jglan brz-css-proqr brz" style="padding: 0px 7.5px 15px 7.5px;">
            <input id="rate" type="text" placeholder="Interest(%)" class="investment-class-form"/>
        </div>
        </label> 
        <label for="time">
            <div>
        <button class="button investment-button" type="submit">Submit </button>
        </div>
        </label>
        
    </form>
    
    <div class="results hide">
        <div class="monthly-payment">
            <p class="brz-css-gdlup">
            <span class="investment-list"><strong>Summary of monthly installments:</strong></span>
            <span class="investment-list" id="payment"></span>
        </p>
        </div>

        <div class="total-interest" >
            <p class="brz-css-gdlup">
            <span class="investment-list"><strong>Summary of interest balance:</strong></span>
            <span class="investment-list" id="interest"></span>
        </p>
        </div>
        <div class="total-amount" >
            <p class="brz-css-gdlup">
            <span class="investment-list"><strong>Total amount:</strong></span>
            <span class="investment-list" id="total"></span>
        </p>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To compound, you have to take power. Use either `Math.pow()` or `**` operator.

Comment: how does the function Math.pow() become applied when calculating the monthly payment?